# Calculate Metrics for Keras CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a CNN model that recognize the human postures in total 4 postures, I would to test the performance of my model by calculating the metrics recall, precision, fmeasure, accuracy. the accuracy is calculated by default in Keras library, but the other one I need to implement them. I found the source code to calculate these metrics but I think the is for binary classification :

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):

true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
return precision

def recall(y_true, y_pred):

true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
return recall


def f1(y_true, y_pred):

def recall(y_true, y_pred):

    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):

    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision
precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer= "adam",
          metrics=[mcor,recall, f1])
```

I think this is for binary classification only, so please I need your help, if I can't use this for multi-label classification, what is the method that I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

as your final output can have 4 labels. in the model.compile part change

`loss='binary_crossentropy'`   to   `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

and in the last layer of your neural network architecture change the activation function to `'softmax'`' also the number of output neurons should be changed.
other changes like your input shape will depend upon the data you are giving to the model.

refer to this blog to know more about CNN.

https://towardsdatascience.com/convolutional-neural-networks-for-beginners-practical-guide-with-python-and-keras-dc688ea90dca

refer to this blog to know more about How to Calculate Precision, Recall, F1, and More for Deep Learning Models

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-calculate-precision-recall-f1-and-more-for-deep-learning-models/

Comment: But I can use these functions on multi-label classification or it is dedicated to binary classification only ? @Siddhant Ranjan

Comment: @SteveMclin yes you can use it and that's why I gave you the link to the blog just go through it you will understand what these functions are and see if there are any changes needed because these functions are implemented here from scratch.